# Chrome tooltips disappearing on textarea update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Trying to figure out how to resolve an issue with Chrome where tooltips are disappearing or won't show up at all when another area of the page is being updated.  It works fine in Firefox.  As soon as the textarea scrolls the tooltip disappears.

Below is some code to demonstrate the problem:

```js
function add_to_log(msg) {
  the_log = document.getElementById("log-area");
  the_log.value += msg;
  the_log.scrollTop = the_log.scrollHeight
}
var counter = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    add_to_log(counter+++"\n")
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="log-area" style="height:40px; width:80px; float:left; "></textarea>
<a title="test tooltip" style="float:left;">mouse over this</a>
```

Comment: Perhaps use an HTML tooltip library like `qTip` instead of native tooltips.

Comment: It works correctly in Chrome version 48, so it appears to be a bug introduced between that version and version 54.

Comment: You could report it to the Chrome team.

Comment: Small reminder that the `title` attribute poses a lot of issues when used as a tooltip for important information.